# Write DataFrame from Azure Databricks notebook to Azure DataLake Gen2 Tables

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I've created a DataFrame which I would like to write / export next to my Azure DataLake Gen2 in Tables (need to create new Table for this).

In the future I will also need to update this Azure DL Gen2 Table with new DataFrames.

In Azure Databricks I've created a connection Azure Databricks -> Azure DataLake to see my my files:

[image]

Appreciate help how to write it in spark / pyspark.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of writing data in parquet format, go for Delta format which internally uses Parquet format but provide other features like ACID transaction.The syntax would be

```
df.write.format("delta").save(path)
```

Comment: Delta Lake is something I will need to really dig deep into :) Best!